# .htaccess isn't redirecting subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have setup an `.htccess` file to redirect www to non-www and also remove trailing slashes. I also have to make sure that `business.domain.com` also redirects (301) to `domain.com`. The other rules work except redirecting `business.domain.com`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect business subdomain to no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^business\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect non-trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas why the 2nd cond/rule isn't taking effect?

Comment: Stupidly I've just realised an .htaccess file was present in the business subdirectory. Renamed that to .htaccess_ and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into a trailing slash. How about either:

```
# redirect business subdomain to no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^business\.(.+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Or just

```
# redirect business subdomain to no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^business\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your information, you're making a mistake when you redirect to a top level domain (unless you have huge bandwidth): setting cookies for a prefixless domain sets them across all subdomains... and sessions *always* set cookies.

Anyway, here's a rule that works flawlessly for me:

```
# If only two groups separated by a '.':
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.(fr|com|net|org|eu) [NC]
# This means there's no www => force redirection:
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.%1$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

And I have the opposite as well:

```
# "business" => no subdomain:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(business\.)mywebsite\.(fr|com|net|org|eu) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.%2$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```